# How to create an array if 'empty'?

Tags: functions, array

Sorry if this is super "newbie", but I'm stumped. I'm trying to create a function in WP All Import that states if the cell is empty it populates with "Not Specified". Please see below:

```
function power_translate_data( $data ) {
    $map = array(
        ' '                     => 'Not Specified',
 );

    foreach ( $map as $partial_match => $mapped_value ) {
        if ( stristr( $data, $partial_match ) ) {
            return $mapped_value;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give. Thank you!

Comment: `stristr` with `' '` will attemp to find the string value of a space in the data. You want to use `if ( trim($data) == $partial_match )` and set the value to `''` (no space)

Comment: @majick that worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- First enable wp_debug log
- Second dump the array errror_log(print_r($map))
- Then look at your data array, and then start out writing the function.
- Sometimes WP All Import is a pain in the ass